# Need sed to remove punctuation

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have an arp-scan that I run from a PHP page.  It discovers specific devices on my network very well.  The only thing is that I have to change the mac info to remove the colons and then make all the letters default to caps.

Here is my command:

```
$output = shell_exec("sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet --numeric --quiet| grep -e 80:82:87");
```

It only retrieves MAC addresses that start with `80:82:87`

I found a sed command to change all the letters to caps but not in this command.
How can I do this?

Comment: Is there some reason you prefer not to use `sed`? `grep` won't do it, but `sed` should be fine I think. Not sure what your issue is.

Comment: When asking a question, you should focus on the specific task at hand, which in no way involves ARP, PHP or MAC addresses.

Comment: Beyond this question, note that you have a mistake in your `grep` which may match against `*80:82:87`.  Prepending it with `^` would force it to match the beginning of the line: `grep -e "^80:82:87"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in `sed` like this:

```
sed -n '/^80:82:87/ { s/;//g; y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/; p }'
```

- The `-n` option tells `sed` not to print its input
  except when specifically directed to do so.
- The `/^80:82:87/` says that the commands inside the `{…}` braces
  should be executed only on lines that begin with `80:82:87`. 
  This gives you the same functionality as the `grep`. 
  You should never need to pipe `grep` into `sed` or `awk`.
- The `s/;//g` command deletes all semicolons in the line,
  which is what you said you want. 
  If you meant colons, then simply change it to `s/://g`.
- The `y` command converts all lowercase (Roman/ASCII) letters to uppercase. 
  If you only need to convert MAC addresses (and/or other hex values),
  you can get by with `y/abcdef/ABCDEF/`.
- Finally, print the modified line.

@jasonwryan has nudged me into realizing that the cumbersome `y` command
can be replaced with `s/[[:lower:]]/\U&/g`, `s/[[:alpha:]]/\U&/g`,
or even `s/.*/\U&/` — but only if you're using GNU sed. 
`\U` doesn't seem to be defined in POSIX.

Comment: Does sed not support character lists?

Comment: @jasonwryan: If I understand what you mean, then the answer is yes and no — yes in `s`, not, as far as I can tell, in `y`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you G-Man  Your explanation helps me understand what is going on.  I will give it a try.

Comment: G-Man  Your solution worked perfectly after I removed the carat before the MAC filter.  With it in there I got no results, without it it is just what I needed.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

`tr` is ideal for simple operations like that:

```
echo '80:82:87:af:d2' | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' | tr -d ':'
```

Answer (score 2):

Awk can do the pattern matching, uppercasing *and* the replacement in one pass:

`awk '/^80:82:87/ {gsub(/:/,""); print toupper($0)}'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm ignoring the fact that this may be best done in PHP (since that's what you're working with) using PHP's string manipulation functions, possibly through something like `$addr = strtoupper(str_replace(":", "", $output))`. Instead I'll focus on a Unix-specific shell solution.

Using Awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS=":"; ORS = "" } { print toupper }' <<<"$mac_address"
```

Testing:

```
$ mac_address="xx:yy:zz:k7:23:f0"
$ awk 'BEGIN { RS=":"; ORS = "" } { print toupper }' <<<"$mac_address"
XXYYZZK723F0
```

The Awk program will read each part of the MAC address as a separate record (a record is otherwise usually a line of input), and print them out without a record separator (the output record separator is otherwise by default a newline). Before printing each record, it converts it to upper case.